# How to convert byte slice received over network to struct

Tags: networking, struct, go

Is there a library function to convert a []byte into a struct? I'm working on a client to catch a struct sent from a server written in C.

I have my struct setup like this.

```
type mystruct struct {
    A   uint32
    B   uint16
}
```

This is how I read the bytes over the wire.

```
var s []byte = make([]byte, 6)
sock.ReadFromUDP(s)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use encoding/binary. 
From the documentation's example: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var pi float64
    b := []byte{0x18, 0x2d, 0x44, 0x54, 0xfb, 0x21, 0x09, 0x40}
    buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &pi)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Read failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Print(pi)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically with structs, it would be something like this.

```
type mystruct struct {
    A   uint32
    B   uint16
}

// ... networking code...

var buff []byte = make([]byte, 6)
sock.ReadFromUDP(buff)

var reader = bytes.NewReader(buff)   
var str mystruct
binary.Read(reader, binary.LittleEndian, &str)

// now str has things
fmt.Println(str.A)
```